# Why Firefox menu button disappeared?

Tags: 13.04, firefox, menu, button, globalmenu

I'm using the latest stable Firefox under Ubuntu 13.04 x64. I disabled menu bar, because using the menu button is more comfortable for me. Until an update (around version 21 or 22) the button just disappeared. I checked the tool bar settings but those are correct, so nothing has been changed. I purged Firefox and removed the cache, but it is still the same. BUT I noticed an exception: if I run Firefox with sudo, the menu button appears.
[I'm talking about this little thing what I miss.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXdCa.jpg)

How can I get it back permanently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm running Firefox 23 in Ubuntu 13.04 with the **Button** instead the **menubar**.

You can try the following..

**1)** Disable the global menu in firefox:

- Open Firefox and in address bar type `about:config` then click to confirm in *"I'll be careful, I promise"*

[image]

- Search the key "ui.use_unity_menubar" and select it , then double click to change the value from true to false.

[image]

[image]

**2)** Right click in the firefox window and *"uncheck"* **Menu Bar**

[image]

After that you should have the Firefox Button instead the menubar.

[image]

Comment: That is what I did but no result. http://i.imgur.com/qaADMJK.jpg

Comment: I Edited my answered. please try to disable the global-menu first, then uncheck the menubar.

Comment: Works also the other way around, when you have the menu button and want to get rid of it: Check that the *Menu Bar* option is checked, which is only visible when `ui.use_unity_menubar` is set to false. :)